# Prove that the intersection of two vector space subset isn't the trivial vector space $\{ 0 \}$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$ vector space with $\dim(V) = n$ and $U_1, U_2 \subseteq V$ subspaces with $\dim(U_1) = j$, $\dim(U_2) = k$. Prove that if $j+k > n$ then it has to be that $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \{ 0 \}$.

I thought maybe to use contradiction, but I am not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: Maybe I just haven't progressed far enough in mathematics, but is a "vector room" a translation of "vector space"?

Comment: I bet so. The literal translation from German to English gives "vector room".

Comment: @HeatTheIce: Your title is misleading. You have to show that the interection is not the trivial vector space $\{0\}$. You **always** have $0 \in U_1 \cup U_2$ for subspaces $U_1, U_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue by contradiction. Assume that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\}$. Take bases $\{a_1,\ldots,a_j\}$ of $U_1$ and $\{b_1, \ldots, b_k\}$ of $U_2$. Now, you should show that the union of these basis is still linear independent.

Comment: How can I do that using the condition that $j+k>n$? The condition is confusing me a bit.

Comment: Because the cardinality of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_j, b_1,\ldots,b_k\}$ is ... and the maximal cardinality of a linear independent set in $V$ is ...

Comment: Can we go with the logic that if $0$ is in $U_1$ and $U_2$ then we have that $a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+...+a_j x_j=b_1 y_1 + b_2 y_2 + ... + b_n y_n=0$, then we have that for the union of these two basis $(a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+...+a_j x_j)+(b_1 y_1 + b_2 y_2 + ... + b_n y_n)=0$. We got now that the amount of basis vectors is $j+k$ which should be $\le n$. This is contradiction with $i+j>n$.

Comment: Is this a valid conlclusion?

Comment: I cannot follow your line of reasoning. In particular, your coefficients $x_i$ and $y_j$ have to be zero by definition of a basis.